# XML from SQL column: Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, xml

I have a sql query that is kicking back with an error on my column name saying 'cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

```
      SELECT [LEARNER_COURSE_XML_TEST].[XML_EX].Query('declare namespace
      x="http://tempuri.org/cmi.xsd";] (/x:cmi/x:core/x:time_taken)') 
      AS TimeTaken FROM [LEARNER_COURSE_XML_TEST]
```

The issue seems to centre around [XML_EX].value but I've tried a few things including changing the column type but i've finally come unstuck.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys. Turns out I was over complicating it as I don't have access to my namespace in the SQL table. I did however start by changing my field type to XML so thanks Andomar. My solution is below:

```
SELECT [LEARNER_COURSE_XML_TEST].[XML_EX].query('data(sco/cmicore/total_time)') AS  TimeTaken FROM [LEARNER_COURSE_XML_TEST]
```

This extracts my total times as i'd hoped. Thanks again.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like `XML_EX` is of type `nvarchar(max)`.  Try changing it to `xml`.

You can also cast it in the query, like so:

```
select  cast(lcxt.XML_EX as xml).query(...)
from    learner_course_xml_test lcxt
```

Comment: `CAST` has to wrap the whole column reference, not just the column name (i.e. `lcxt.` should be inside)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Obviously right, feel free to edit ;)